# Unknown Database Error in MySql and Java

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc

I am tried connect to database using this **Java** code :

```
try {       
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://11.11.111.111:3306/srfms";
        Connection connection = null; 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "password");

        if(!connection.isClosed())
             out.println("Successfully connected to " + "MySQL server using TCP/IP...");

        connection.close();        
    }catch(Exception ex){
        out.println(ex);
    }
```

And this code working successfully.But I must work also another Spring MVC code but this code doesn't work and this is **database.properties** :

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql:////11.11.111.111:3306/srfms
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=password
```

**And error is : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'srfms'**

**Edit :** jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql:////11.11.111.111:3306/srfms : There is two extra "/" is my problem.**Problem is solved.**

Comment: Are you sure that database `srfms` exists on host where you try to connect?

Comment: Yes I'm sure I try above code and is exist I executed several queries.

Comment: First code is in another project the second project contain above database.properties file.First code is working but second project doesn't working throw "unknown database" exception.

Comment: You should provide sample of the code that is not working, ie the Spring MVC one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Ivan this is helped me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created *srfms* database ?

Or you can try this :

```
public class MyConnect {
         String servername ;String port ;
         String db_name ;
         String db_user;
         String db_pass;
     public MyConnect() {
         servername = "127.0.0.1";
         port = "3306";
         db_name = "school";
         db_user="root";
         db_pass="";
     }

     public MyConnect(String servername, String port, String db_name, String db_user, String
db_pass) {
         this.servername = servername;
         this.port = port;
         this.db_name = db_name;
         this.db_user = db_user;
         this.db_pass = db_pass;
       }

     public Connection getcn()
    {
         Connection cn = null;
         try {
         String db_url = "jdbc:mysql://" + servername + ":" + port +"/" + db_name;
         System.out.println(db_url);
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         cn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, db_user, db_pass);
       }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
       }
       return cn;
     }
}
```